# string builder to string

Tags: c#, string

I am using the code below to build a string with a format, I want to convert this into a normal string as the message in the string will be a sent an email. How can I make this into a table format? The output I get is this would all be printed belwor in a single line in a email, I would like to see it so its actually well laid out

```
   <table>
       <tr>
         <td>as</td>
         <td>Success</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>as</td>
         <td>Success</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

---

```
myString.Append("<table>");
var activityLog = TwitterData.GetActivityLog();
for (int i = 0; i < activityLog.Rows.Count;i++ )
{
    myString.Append("<tr>");
    myString.Append("<td>" + activityLog.Rows[i]["PageName"].ToString() + "</td>");
    myString.Append("<td>" + activityLog.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString() + "</td>");
    myString.Append("</tr>");
}

myString.Append("</table>");
```

wanted ouput

```
Name   |  log
as     |   success
as     |   success
```

Comment: What is a _"table format"_?

Comment: I am geting the data form a datatable,

Comment: Are you maybe sending that text as a *plain text* email, instead of an *HTML formatted* one?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "table format"?

Comment: @Sansx: your "improved formatting" is just an assumption.

Comment: Hurry up mate, everyone is downvoting for leaving an unclear question and staying silence for long time. People don't like hanging around here. *lol*

Comment: done soory for the delay

Comment: The edit came one second too late. Now it's clear. You want to add the header to the table. You just have to use the code from the loop before it with the two static columns "Name" and "Log".

Comment: Are you looking for something as simple as changing `StringBuilder.Append` to `StringBuilder.AppendLine`?

Comment: yes, but the view still doesnt come in the actual output in that format

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the .net mail client, indicate the body is HTML.

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.Body = myString.ToString();
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Remember that your `myString` is a `StringBuilder` and needs to be converted to a `string`.

Comment: the ouput comes after i have converted it

Comment: "the output comes after i have converted it" ? Lost and confused here....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need this formatted as *plain-text* you could do something like

```
myString.Append("<table>");
var activityLog = TwitterData.GetActivityLog();
for (int i = 0; i < activityLog.Rows.Count;i++ )
{
    myString.AppendFormat("{0}<tr>{0}\t<td>{1}</td>{0}\t<td>{2}</td>{0}</tr>{0}", Environment.NewLine, activityLog.Rows[i]["PageName"], activityLog.Rows[i]["Status"]);
}
myString.Append("</table>");
```

Sample program

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<table>");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}<tr>{0}\t<td>{1}</td>{0}\t<td>{2}</td>{0}</tr>{0}", Environment.NewLine, "field1", "field2");
}
sb.Append("</table>");
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

**Output**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>field1</td>
    <td>field2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>field1</td>
    <td>field2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>field1</td>
    <td>field2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>field1</td>
    <td>field2</td>
</tr>
```